# BCD to 7 Segment Decoder Schematic : Need help fitting in page

Tags: boolean-logic, xilinx, bcd

I am working on the schematic for a BCD to 7 segment decoder right now. I understand the logic, but it is the design of the schematic that I need help with.

[image: Here is my schematic so far.]

As you can see, I only have three outputs done and I need to add four more. The problem that I am having is everything is so vertical and there is so much white space to the right. I would like to be able to fit in all in one page without having to zoom really far out, because then you can't read the inputs or outputs. I guess I just feel like there is a more simple or effecient way that I can be doing this. In the truth table we are using 1010-1110 as don't cares, and 1111 as 0 for all segments to be off.
I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a programming Q&A site, you might find the electronics site better suited to this question.  That being said, Try staggering the gates and outputs, i.e.

```
-----|\
     | o---------------------
-----|/      |-----|\
-------------|     | o-------
-------------------|/
-----|\
     | o---------------------
-----|/
```